# Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: quick

Tags: qt, qt-quick

```
$ qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

The ***.pro*** file is here:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

QT       += quick
SOURCES  = qtCppIntegration.cpp
```

qmake ***results in:***

```
$ qmake  
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: quick
```

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIR in Qt 4.8 this module is called `declarative`. `Quick` is for Qt5

Comment: my problem is not solve. i add this and remove `quick.TEMPLATE = app

QT += declarative
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)`